# Implications of not setting android:targetSdkVersion

Tags: android-manifest

What, if any, are the implications of not setting android:targetSdkVersion in your Android manifest file ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this helps you:

> With this attribute set, the application says that it is able to run
>   on older versions (down to minSdkVersion), but was explicitly tested
>   to work with the version specified here. Specifying this target
>   version allows the platform to disable compatibility settings that are
>   not required for the target version (which may otherwise be turned on
>   in order to maintain forward-compatibility) or enable newer features
>   that are not available to older applications. This does not mean that
>   you can program different features for different versions of the
>   platform—it simply informs the platform that you have tested against
>   the target version and the platform should not perform any extra work
>   to maintain forward-compatibility with the target version.

Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

I never had any problems leaving it blank. I always set it the version of my own device.